# Custom notification is not creating when I add custom layout

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview, android-version, custom-notification

I have to create a custom notification like what's app calling notification. Notification does not create if I add my custom layout to the NotificationCompat Builder. Below is my code to create notification.
Creating Notification

```
   context?.let {

        val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(it.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification_collapsed)
        val notificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(it.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification)

        notificationLayout.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_icon, R.drawable.icon)
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_app_name, it.getString(R.string.app_name))
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.time_stamp, it.getString(R.string.just_now))

        notificationLayoutExpanded.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_icon,R.drawable.icon)
        notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_app_name, it.getString(R.string.app_name))
        notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.content, it.getString(R.string.text))
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.time_stamp, it.getString(R.string.just_now))

        var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(it, AppConstants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setTicker("Noification is created")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)


        var customNotificationCompat: NotificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(it)
        customNotificationCompat.notify(0, builder.build())

    }
```

Creating Channel and calling it from Application class:

```
    fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
        val descriptionText = context.getString(R.string.text)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(AppConstants.CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your custom layout has only `View`s that are allowed in `RemoteViews`? You can't use just anything for those; only a certain set.

Comment: Yes, I have figured out.